# mysqldump should prompt for password

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

When I'm executing mysqldump command from localhost or from remote host, it's not prompting me for password. I want the password prompt even though I'm running it from remote or from local. 
On my server there is no ~/.my.cnf present. Also I have Ubuntu server. I'm running mariadb. Also I would like to know how mysqldump command pick up a password everytime ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter a password manually each time you invo `mysqldump` you should use the `-p` option:

```
  -p, --password[=name] 
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's solicited on the tty.
```

If you do not specify the password in the commandline, it will ask you to enter one.

Answer (score 0):

From `mariadb` [website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/), you can see:

```
Options

mysqldump supports the following options, which can be specified on the
command line or in the [mysqldump] and [client] option file groups. Default
options are read from the following files in the given order:

    1. /etc/my.cnf
    2. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    3. /usr/etc/my.cnf
    4. ~/.my.cnf 

mysqldump also supports the options for processing option files
```

So you should check that no password option for mysqldump is specified in all these files.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you have specified a password for the `root@localhost` user in MariaDB users table.